# checkbox en angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Hola a todos resulta que tengo el siguiente switch:

`<div>
<input class="cheqb" type="checkbox" ng-model="checkstate" ng-change="verificarCheckbox()"> <span>Acepto las condiciones establecidas en las <a href="#" target="_blank">Bases Legales</a> del concurso</span>
</div>`

la cual necesito controlar su estado para poder hacer una peticion al servidor:

`$scope.send = function (formData) {

```
var terminos;
var spam = 2;
  $scope.verificarCheckbox = function(){
      if($scope.checkstate){
         terminos =1;
      }else{
         terminos =0;
      }
  }

  console.log(terminos);
  var name = formData.nombre;
  var correo = formData.email;
  var rut = formData.rut;
  var region = formData.region;

 if (name == undefined || correo == undefined || rut == undefined || region == undefined) {

    console.log('campos vacios');

  }

  else {
    conection.registro({

      id: localStorage.getItem("code"),
      nombre: formData.nombre,
      correo: formData.email,
      rut: formData.rut,
      region: formData.region,
      cond1: terminos,
      cond2: spam

    }, function(response){

      swal({
 title: 'Registro Exitoso!',
 timer: 2000,
  type: 'success'}).then(
 function () {},
 // handling the promise rejection
 function (dismiss) {
   if (dismiss === 'timer') {
     console.log('I was closed by the timer')
   }
 }
```

)

```
          $location.path('/Bienvenido');
          $location.hash('feed');

    });
  }

  };`
```

mi objetivo es que si es `true` que mande 0 de lo contrario que mande 1

y no resulta manda solo 1, en el código de la consulta, la funcion la puse dentro de `$scope.send` que cuando hace click al llenar el fomulario, favor ayuda.

Comment: Que te muestra la consola del navegador ???

Comment: en consola muestra undefined

Comment: Seria de mucha ayuda para comprender mejor el problema que incluyas el código completo, por ejemplo en https://jsfiddle.net/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas verificando fuera de la funcion, por lo tanto el dato no existe.

```html
$scope.verificarCheckbox = function(){
      if($scope.checkstate){
         terminos =1;
      }else{
         terminos =0;
      }
console.log(terminos);
  }
```

Prueba metiendo dentro de la función asi como te puse en el ejemplo

Comment: listo lo solucione, gracias.

Comment: Por nada, Saludos desde Paraguay